# What is the function of node in linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am creating a linked list from scratch. Here is the code. at first, I have defined `node *root=NULL;`

that means root node has no element. But when I append the first element I have to create `root=new node();`

is not it that `node *root=NULL;` has created a root node? then why I have to use `root=new node();`.

actually i am confused among `node *root=NULL;` & `root=new node();` & `root==NULL`'. would you please make me understand?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int roll;
    node *next;

};

node *root=NULL;

void append(int roll)
{
    if( root==NULL)
    {
        root=new node();
        root->roll=roll;
        root->next=NULL;

    }
    else
    {
        node *current_node=root;


        while(current_node->next!=NULL)

        {
            current_node=current_node->next;

        }
        node *newnode=NULL;
        newnode=new node();
        newnode->roll=roll;
        newnode->next=NULL;
        current_node->next=newnode;


    }
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)

Comment: Don't use `NULL` in modern C++. Use `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you have to understand what pointers are. Basicall they hold memory adresses.

> is not it that node `*root=NULL;` has created a root node?

No. `root` is no `node`, but a pointer *to* a `node`. It is initialized with `NULL` (in C++ `nullptr` should be preferred), so it doesn't point to any object yet.

> then why I have to use `root=new node();`

`new node()` will allocate and initialize a new object of type `node` on the heap and return a pointer to this object. This pointer is then assigned to `root` - now `root` points to an actual object of type `node`.

> actually i am confused among node `*root=NULL;` & `root=new node();` & `root==NULL`.

I hope the first two are clear by now. `root == NULL` simply checks if the value of `root` is `NULL`, this is if `root` points to an actual object. Again, `nullptr` should be preferred here.

Comment: can i use *root==NULL instead of root==NULL?

Comment: @imtinan No. This would mean "take the object `root` is pointing to (`*root`) and check if this object is equal to `NULL`". But you can't compare a `node` to a number.

Answer (score 1):

Your linked list will be a, well, list of `nodes` that are connected by pointers.

If you assign `node *root = nullptr;`, you will not be able to access any member of `root`. After all, root does not point to a node but to `nullprt`. `root = new Node()` creates a new Node element using the default constructor. You will now be able to access the members of this element. This is why `root->rool` and `root->next` will work now.

`node *root`: Declares that root is a pointer to a `node`.

`root = NULL`: Seems old fashioned to me, but will assign the [pointer to a nullprt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL).

`root = new node()`: Assigns root to an instance of `node` that was created using the default constructor.

`root == nullprt`: True if root is a nullptr.

Answer (score 0):

The reason lies in the `else`.

You are looking for the end of the current list, and you append an element. To achieve this, you change the `next` pointer of the current last node (which is `NULL` as it's the last) to point to the new node.

But what happens if there is no node at all in the list? There is no `next` pointer to modify, and you can't append: you have to create a first node, which will not be the `next` of any other node. This case is not dealt with in the `else` clause, it's the `root=new node();` that annoys you.

---

A remark. Usually one does not append, because you then have to scan the whole list.

If you really want to append, it's better to keep track of the pointer to the last element. You have two pointers then: the root and the last. The root is still necessary to be able to scan the list.

And if you don't keep track of the last pointer, the best is to always prepend (if you wish, you can pretend the last element of the list is the root node). It's what is usually done for a FIFO stack.

Incidentally, when you prepend, you don't have to deal with the initially `NULL` root: this `NULL` will become the `next` pointer of the first node, and there is nothing else to do.